# Iteratively parse 100s of large nested JSON files for each instance of two keys and their values and export to a CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

I am trying to parse a JSON file of the following structure:

```
{"General info": [
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    },
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    }
],
"Disclosure": [
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    },
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    }
],
"Insurance": [
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    },
    {
        "section": "stuff",
        "sub-section": "stuff",
        "heading": "stuff",
        "field": "X",
        "value": "Y"
    }
 ]}
```

I have 10 keys at the root level, and each has a list of dictionaries with the same set of keys as shown above. I am only interested in getting the "field" and "value" keys and their respective values for each case. To clarify, the above is a severely cropped version. The real JSON files contain hundreds of dictionaries within each list of dictionaries that branch out from the root keys, not just two each as shown above.

In total, I have 500 JSON files of the above structure and I need to convert the "field" keys into columns (which are consistent across all 500 JSON files) and the "value" values into data entries such that I have 500 rows, one for each JSON file parsed.

The output in CSV would then look like this:

| File | Field1 | Field 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | value | value | ... |
| file2 | value | value | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I was left some scripts by someone else to help with this task but they have used several scripts and are defining every heading and root section individually. This no longer works as some of the headings etc have changed and there are so many (100s of them) to go through that I feel a more general approach would be better.

I have seen general solutions online but I could not work out how to implement them for my use case - especially looping through lots of JSON files and exporting each parsed JSON to a single row in a CSV.

I can get all the JSON files using this code:

```
# get all of the JSON files
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('my JSON directory'):
    for file in files:
        opened_file = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        # json_data_string = opened_file.read()
        json_data = json.load(opened_file)
        # print(json_data, flush=True)
        parsed_json_dicts.append(json_data)
        filepath_list.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))
        # parsed_json_dfs.append(pd.json_normalize(json_data))
        opened_file.close()
print(len(filepath_list))
```

Comment: Did you omit the "root level" curly braces in the JSON example... is it really `{ "General info": ... }`?

Comment: @ZachYoung Yes, good catch! I will amend that

Answer (score 1):

The following script will read you sample input, copied into two different files, and produce the following CSV:

| File | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5 | Field 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| json_files/input.json | X | X | X | X | X | X |
| json_files/input copy.json | X | X | X | X | X | X |

One significant difference is that this code uses `with open(...) as f` "context managers" (or something like that), so we don't to explicitly call close() on file objects (the file will automatically be closed when everything under the `with open...` is finished and that block of code goes out of scope):

```py
import csv
import json
import os

rows = []
max_cols = 0

for subdir, dirs, file_names in os.walk("json_files"):
    for fname in file_names:
        json_path = os.path.join(subdir, fname)
        with open(json_path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)

            row = [json_path]
            for categories in data.values():
                for category in categories:
                    row.append(category["field"])

            rows.append(row)

            if len(row) > max_cols:
                max_cols = len(row)


header = ["File"]
for i in range(1, max_cols):
    header.append(f"Field {i}")


with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

You'll need to wrap the `with open("...json")...` block with your JSON-file iterator, everything else should remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! When you say I need to wrap that block with my JSON-file iterator, how would that be done? 
`for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        opened_file = open(os.path.join(subdir, file))`
and then your code all indented in this?

Comment: This is very close to what I am after excecpt the fields in the CSV columns should be the values from the 'field' key in each instance, i.e. X in the sample given. I should have clarified this in the post - amending now! @zachyoung

Comment: @SJPJack, updated the code to reflect your questions.